# How to define array of objects in side nested array mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an express API using an already populated mongoDB and have defined the schema like so:

```
const accountHolderSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  pid: {Type: Number},
  accountNumber: {type: String},
  relationshipType: {type: String},
  firstName: {type: String},
  middleName: {type: String},
  lastName: {type: String}
});

const accountsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  accountNumber: String,
  accountType: String,
  accountHolder: [accountHolderSchema]
});


const productDetailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  pid: Number,
  accounts: [accountsSchema]
});
```

I have literally copied and paste all the properties and from the database so i know they match so i know that's out of the picture

The RESPONSE I get is this:

```
{
"pid": 2697143,
    "accounts": [
        {
            "accountHolders": [
                {
                    "pid": 13209741,
                    "accountNumber": "403716000062",
                    "relationshipType": "BENEFICIARY",
                    "firstName": "Maria",
                    "middleName": "Delores",
                    "lastName": "Jackson"
                }
             ]
            "accountNumber": "12345",
            "accountType": "RSA",
        }
     ]
}
```

BUT what the response I WANT to get in return is this:

```
{
"pid": 2697143,
    "accounts": [
        {
            "accountNumber": "12345",
            "accountType": "RSA",
            "accountHolders": [
                {
                    "pid": 13209741,
                    "accountNumber": "403716000062",
                    "relationshipType": "BENEFICIARY",
                    "firstName": "Maria",
                    "middleName": "Delores",
                    "lastName": "Jackson"
                }
             ]
        }
     ]
}
```

I want the **accountNumber** and **accountNumber** to come before **accountHolders** field.

I'm not sure if its the way how i define a nested array inside of another nested array that's throwing of the structure. If I don't the define **accountHolderSchema** the structure is returned fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Try rearranging  accountSchema backwards, sounds stupid but maybe works :)

Comment: @vitomadio that doesn't work

Comment: How does the order affect your code ?

Comment: JavaScript Objects have no *guaranteed* order of keys, **nor should they**. Whilst *most* engines do respect *"insertion order"* it is not absolute and quite often there is underlying code processing things ( very true with mongoose documents ) that may change the order of appearance. In short you really should not care which order keys appear in for a data structure. If you **do care** then the data should be rearranged into an array for the processing in which you absolutely require it in a certain order.

Comment: @NeilLunn the order doesn't really affect functionality because the data is still being return. I just wanted the response that's return from my api to match the document structure i defined in the mongoose schema.

Comment: The point is that just because that's the order you defined in the schema this does not mean the order of keys returned is *guaranteed* in any way. Also as I said *"you really should not care"*, and though it may be a *want* you should simply *accept* that the order should not matter. If you think it matters, then transpose the results to an *array* or *Map* which are the only things that *guarantee* a returned order. Which is also what linked answers say.

Comment: Okay noted. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the propreties is really important to you, you could use some simple JavaScript.
Loop through your Schema propreties and assign the propreties to an `obj`.

(`Object.keys(obj)`) will return an array with the propreties, then you make an organized copy of your document by getting the keys from the array and assigning values from the document.

```js
let schema = {
"pid": 2697143,
    "accounts": [
        {
            "accountNumber": "12345",
            "accountType": "RSA",
            "accountHolders": [
                {
                    "pid": 13209741,
                    "accountNumber": "403716000062",
                    "relationshipType": "BENEFICIARY",
                    "firstName": "Maria",
                    "middleName": "Delores",
                    "lastName": "Jackson"
                }
             ]
        }
     ]
}
let doc = {
"pid": 2697143,
    "accounts": [
        {
            "accountHolders": [
                {
                    "pid": 13209741,
                    "accountNumber": "403716000062",
                    "relationshipType": "BENEFICIARY",
                    "firstName": "Maria",
                    "middleName": "Delores",
                    "lastName": "Jackson"
                }
             ],
            "accountNumber": "12345",
            "accountType": "RSA",
        }
     ]
}

let docOrganized= {};
docOrganized.pid = doc.pid;
Object.keys(schema.accounts[0]).map(key => docOrganized[key] = doc.accounts[0][key]);
console.log(docOrganized);
```